# Include specific column from related-models table

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, relational-database

Using Laravel 5.1: Given two related models, `User` and `Item`, with through table `Item_User`, how can I include a specific column from the through table, **item_count** using a `with` statement?

`Item_User` table:

[image]

Query:

```
    $userGameProfile = User::with([
        'items' => function($query) use ($profile_id) {
            $query->with(['phrases'])->where('profile_id', '=', $profile_id);
        }])->find($id);
```

Adding `->select('item_count')` to this query only returns item count, and not the related item objects. Adding `->select('*')` gets me the items and fields I want, but breaks the nested `with(['phrases'])` relationship I need to get related phrases to items.

I was told I should use `withPivot`, but I cannot find documentation or examples on how to use this.

Preferably, I'd like to add this to the relationship, rather than each query.

**Models**:

`User`:

```
public function items()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class, 'user_item');
}
```

`Item`:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_item');
}
public function phrases()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Phrase::class, 'item_phrase');
}
```

`Phrase`:

```
public function items()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class, 'item_phrase');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/) highlights how to include additional information from the `pivot table`.

In `User` model, I know I will always want to include `item_count` from `user_items` pivot table, so you can add `withPivot` to the relation to `items`:

```
public function items()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class, 'user_item')
        ->withPivot('item_count');
}
```

`User` now comes back with `items` and pivot data:

[image]